# golangでGoogleの共有ドライブをGoogle drive api v3でGUI上の「共有ドライブの設定」について変更したい

Tags: go, google-drive-sdk

【やりたいこと】
Google ドライブ https://drive.google.com/ の左側 [共有ドライブ] を押し、そこに表示される共有ドライブの中から特定のドライブを右クリックで表示される [共有ドライブの設定] をAPIで変更したい。

【試したこと】
リンクを参考にパラメータの"DomainUsersOnly"と”DriveMembersOnly "にtrueとfalseを設定して共有ドライブを作成したが、GUIから確認するとチェックがついたままでかわらなかった。

リンク：https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api@v0.52.0/drive/v3#DriveRestrictions

Answer (score 0):

update()でパラメータを指定したら変更できました。
create()時はパラメータが利用できないのかも